# Is drunk driving a malum prohibitum or malum in se?

Tags: criminal-law, legal-terms, common-law

In common-law jurisdictions where driving a motor vehicle under the influence of alcohol is illegal (presumably all of them?), is drunk driving considered *malum prohibitum* or *malum in se*?

I am aware that the difference between *malum prohibitum* and *malum in se* is largely academic today, but my understanding is that the distinction does technically still exist.

Comment: @WeatherVane murder is illegal, but isn't it *malum in se*?

Comment: One follows the other. A law usually formalises a community view.

Answer (score 5):

Drunk driving considered *malum prohibitum*. The place that the line is drawn for the offense is arbitrary and it doesn't inherently harm another person.

In contrast, the closely related driving offense of reckless driving is a close call.

And, obviously, vehicular assault or vehicular homicide, which can qualify as such due to drunk driving, is *malum in se*.